# Woocommerce order name value

Tags: php, woocommerce

For a purpose im passing woocommerce values to an array like this :

```
    'name' => $_POST['billing_first_name'],
    'phone' => $_POST['billing_phone'],
    'email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
    'note' => $_POST['order_comments'],
```

Now I'm stuck finding one of the values. The name of the ordered product.

[image]

```
'subject' => HERE GOES THE PRODUCT NAME VALUE,
```

i have been looking everywhere, tried some stuff but nothing worked so far.

I'm working in `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

Retrieved the name like this

```
 // Retrieve order name 

    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $_product = $values['data']->post; 

    } 
    //
```

and then i called it like this

```
'subject' => $_product->post_title,
```